# How to check if modem firmware was updated?

Tags: firmware

I can access cable modem web interface, I can see firmware name... but with what do I compare it to? How do I find out if it is old or new?

Answer (score 1):

There are no general ways for that.

In most cases, you can check the homepage of the hardware vendors to get the newest firmware images, and compare their version to yours.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to simply look at the version of the firmware, try to figure out what is the brand of that modem(see any trace of brand covered by your ISP logo, turn your modem upside down and look for any info, or anything on the web interface that could lead to that) and search at the manufacturer page if there is new firmware available. You will lose time to get frustrated and know the truth that is everywhere: Not all ISPs keep their firmware up-to-date, even when a lot of threats emerge today.

However, it's almost sure that your ISP could be distributing a customized version of firmware, and your device could be BRICKED if you try to push a firmware that is not created by your ISP.

**tl,dr**: You will have to rely on your ISP to deliver updated firmware to your cable modem